# Scrapy: How to efficiently follow nested links with similar css selectors?

Tags: python, web, recursion, web-scraping, scrapy

I have something similar to following code. I know that in this example it would be possible to navigate directly to [the yourself tag page](https://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/yourself/page/1/), but in my application I need to go to page 1 in order to get the links to go to page 2, and I need the links from page 2 in order to get to page 3, etc. (i.e. the urls don't follow a specific pattern).

```
import scrapy


class SampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "sample"
    start_urls = [
        "https://quotes.toscrape.com/",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.css(
            'a[class="tag"][href*=inspirational]::attr(href)'
        ).extract()
        for link in links:
            yield response.follow(link, self.parse_inspirational)

    def parse_inspirational(self, response):
        links = response.css('a[class="tag"][href*=life]::attr(href)').extract()
        for link in links:
            yield response.follow(link, self.parse_life)

    def parse_life(self, response):
        links = response.css('a[class="tag"][href*=yourself]::attr(href)').extract()
        for link in links:
            yield response.follow(link, self.parse_yourself)

    def parse_yourself(self, response):
        for resp in response.css('span[itemprop="text"]::text').extract():
            print(resp)
```

Since the same pattern of following a link and looking for a new css pattern is repeated 3 times, **I want to write a function that would iterate over a list of css strings and recursively yield the responses**. This is what I thought of, but it doesn't work. I'm expecting something that prints the same output as the original/long-version code:

```
def parse_recurse(self, response, css_str=None):
    links = response.css(css_str.pop(0)).extract()
    for link in links:
        yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse_recurse, cb_kwargs={"css_str":css_str})
        
def parse(self, response):
    css = ['a[class="tag"][href*=inspirational]::attr(href)',
           'a[class="tag"][href*=life]::attr(href)',
           'a[class="tag"][href*=yourself]::attr(href)']
    response = self.parse_recurse(response, css_str=css)
    for resp in response.css('span[itemprop="text"]::text').extract():
        print(resp)
```

Comment: scrapy doesn't work as you expect. You can't do `response = self.parse_recurse(...)` because `parse_recurse` doesn't yield `response` but `requests` and normally `Scrapy` catch this request and send it to `engine` which will send request to server and get response from server - and engine will send  response to `callback`. You should rather yield `follow()` with extra parameter which count level of recursion and when level is 3 then it should use callback=parse instead of `parse_recurse`. OR every `parse_recurse` should check len of `css` and use this to send last requests to `callback=parse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do `response = self.parse_recurse(...)` because `parse_recurse` yields only `request`, not `response`.

Normally function yield `request` and Scrapy catch it and it sends `request` to `engine` which will later send `request` to server, ang get `response` from server, and execute `callback` with this `response`.

See details in documentation: [Architecture overview](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html)

You have to use `start_requests` to run `parse_request` with list `css`, and
it should check if `css` is not empty. If `css` is not empty then yield request with callback `parse_requests` and with smaller `css` (so it runs recursion). And if `css` is empty then it should yield request with callback `parse` which will get text.

```
import scrapy

class SampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "sample"
    
    start_urls = ["https://quotes.toscrape.com/"]

    road = [
        'a[class="tag"][href*=inspirational]::attr(href)',
        'a[class="tag"][href*=life]::attr(href)',
        'a[class="tag"][href*=yourself]::attr(href)',
    ]
    
    def start_requests(self):
        """Run starting URL with full road."""
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_recurse, cb_kwargs={"road": self.road})
        
    def parse_recurse(self, response, road):
        """If road is not empty then send to parse_recurse with smaller road.
           If road is empty then send to parse."""

        first = road[0]
        rest  = road[1:]
        
        links = response.css(first).extract()
        
        if rest:
            # repeat recursion
            for link in links:
                yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse_recurse, cb_kwargs={"road": rest})
        else:
            # exit recursion
            for link in links:
                yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse)
            
    def parse(self, response):
        for resp in response.css('span[itemprop="text"]::text').extract():
            print(resp)
            
# --- run without project and save in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    # save in file CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEEDS': {'output.csv': {'format': 'csv'}},  # new in 2.1
})
c.crawl(SampleSpider)
c.start()
```

Comment: Phenomenal answer!! This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: see image which shows how scrapy works - [Architecture overview](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html)